# How to display the names of the sheets of xls file using PHPexcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

How to display the names of the sheets of xls file using PHPexcel?

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0); ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$objPHPExcel->getSheetNames();
```

will return a list of all worksheet names

```
$objWorksheet->getTitle();
```

will return the name of the worksheet in $objWorksheet

**EDIT**

How to access a sheet by name/title:

```
$objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName('Worksheet1');
```

Comment: many thanks. I still found

    $worksheetNames = $objReader->listWorksheetNames($inputFileName);
        

        foreach ($worksheetNames as $sheetName) {
   
     echo $sheetName, '<br />';
        }

Comment: @user1303538 - there's a host of examples in /Tests and documentation in the /Document folders in the distribution that explain all this

Answer (score 0):

its return all sheet in an array

```
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel');
    $excelReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($fileTempName);
    $excelObj = $excelReader->load($fileTempName);
    //$worksheet = $excelObj->getSheet(0);
    $worksheet = $excelObj->getSheetNames();

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($worksheet);
    die;
```